# Gulp Plugin for Validating Swagger Documents?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, swagger

I've decided the most logical way to maintain an enormous Swagger document is to decompose it into node modules and then have a Gulp task that builds them all together. I would however like to validate the Swagger after it's written. Is there a plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) to validate your Swagger. There is no gulp plug-in at this time but you don't really need it, you can either use Swagger Tools's command line interface or use it as a regular module in your `gulpfile`.

Comment: I looked at swagger-tools, but I was unable to find anything in the docs that will scan my swagger document and tell me where the errors are. Could you point me in that direction?

Comment: Here is the docs file for validation https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/docs/Swagger_Validation.md